# c# html array of form elements

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div id="elem">
        <div class="fields">
            <select name="items[1][0]" id="items[1][0]">
            <option value="1">Book</option>
            <option value="2">Brush</option>
            </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="text" value="1" name="items[1][1]" id="items[1][1]">&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a id="test" href="#">Remove Item</a>
        </div>
    </div>       
    </div><a href="#" id="addElem">Add Item</a></div>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="name" value="Submit" />
}
```

Basically, it has a set of two fields a name field and a serial field but defined in a two dimensional array. The `Add Item` link works in a way that when a user clicks on, it adds a new set of fields with the id being the current time `var new_id = new Date().getTime();` using JavaScript. So for example, the new set of fields would be:

```
<div class="fields">
<select name="items[1368034980308][0]" id="items[1368034980308][0]">
<option value="1">Book</option>
<option value="2">Brush</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="items[1368034980308][1]" id="softwarePerAsset[1368034980308][1]">
</div>
```

I would like to submit them to an edit action where the edit action will go through the `items` array and add the two fields.

My Edit action looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(FormCollection col, string[,] items)
{
    return View();
}
```

I have set a break point on the this action but the `items` array is empty and I can only access the fields through the `FormCollection col` variable.

Is there something I am missing for the `items` array not to be set properly.

Comment: If you vote down, please do care and comment why. Thank you.

Comment: Is the first time I see this. Normally to get an array in a form, you only need to add an empty [] after the name of the array and input. I think your best choice is use jQuery to build a JSON with the array, and later send the JSON in a post.

Comment: Yes that is what I ended up doing. My solution is posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Json to the rescue. I redesigned the form to look like this using an idea from this blog (http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) especially the section with **Non-Sequential Indices** as I am adding them using using a timestamp:

```
<div class="fields">
 <input type="hidden" name="items.Index" value="1" />
 <select name="items[1].name" id="items[1].name">
  <option value="1">Visio</option>
  <option value="2">Painter</option>
 </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <input type="text" name="items[1].serial" id="items[1].serial" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <a id="test" href="#">Remove Item</a>
</div>
```

In my controller, I then serialize the FormCollection variable to json which is much easier to manipulate:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(FormCollection col)
{
 string json = JSONHelper.ToJSON(col);
 return View();
}
```

An example of the `json` string would look like this:

```
{ "btnSubmit" : "Submit",
  "items.Index" : "1,2,1368212161686,1368212162374,1368212162966,1368212163750",
  "items[1368212161686].name" : "1",
  "items[1368212161686].serial" : "",
  "items[1368212162374].name" : "2",
  "items[1368212162374].serial" : "",
  "items[1368212162966].name" : "1",
  "items[1368212162966].serial" : "98765",
  "items[1368212163750].name" : "2",
  "items[1368212163750].serial" : "43210",
  "items[1].name" : "1",
  "items[1].serial" : "12345",
  "items[2].name" : "2",
  "items[2].serial" : "67890"
}
```

I had to create a ToJSON extension to be able to retrieve values or else only names were being retrieved

```
public static class JSONHelper
    {
        public static string ToJSON(this System.Web.Mvc.FormCollection collection)
        {
            var list = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (string key in collection.Keys)
            {
                list.Add(key, collection[key]);
            }
            return new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(list);
        }
    }
```